# Why raising a vector of negative values to a fractional power gives NaN

Tags: r, vector, nan, exponential

If I generate a vector of values, some of which are negative:

```
d <- rnorm(1000, 4, 10)
z <- sapply(d, function(x) x^1.2)
```

`z` will contain a mix of real values and `NaN`s. Any values that were originally negative in the vector will be `NaN`.

Why is this? How can I fix it?

Comment: The usual definition of `x^1.2` is `exp(1.2*log(x))`.  Since `log(x)` gives a NaN for a negative value, you get a NaN for the result.  You could try `sign(x)*abs(x)^1.2` and get a value, but it's a stretch to call it `x^1.2`.

Comment: Edit, made a mistake on this post.

Comment: OK, got it, ty. Did not realize raising to a power was defined via exp().

Comment: Another way of going around would be to tell R to treat `d` as a constant via `as.complex(d)^1.2`.

Comment: Could someone point me to where this is in the docs?

Comment: See `?"^"`, which refers you to the documentation for the C `pow()` function.

Comment: What about changing the title to say "to a fractional power"?  Integer powers work the way you would expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `complex` numbers, like below

```
(d + 0i)^1.2
```

Comment: Do you know where the value of `complexNumber^1.2` is documented?  Mathematically there are 5 possible values for it, but because 1.2 can't be represented exactly, there are actually many more in R.  Presumably it's the "principal branch", but I don't see that mentioned in the docs.

Comment: @user2554330, good question. The underlying code [uses the `cpow()` C library function if it's available](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf); I'm sure there's an IEEE/C99 standard under it. e.g. [this IBM documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=functions-cpow-cpowf-cpowl-calculate-complex-power) says  "... with a branch cut for the first parameter along the negative real axis" (also see [here](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)) (ISO/IEC 9899:TC3)

Comment: @user2554330 for complex number, if it is represented in a polar form, say, `x = r*exp(i*theta)`, then `x^1.2` can be written as `r^1.2*exp(i*1.2*theta)`, and I think that is the reason you get one value only.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding:  Yes, but `r^1.2*exp(i*1.2*(theta + 2*pi*k))` is an equally valid answer for any integer `k`.  I think the docs for `cpow()` say that `theta` is chosen in the range `[-pi, pi)` and `k` is zero.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to a comment on a post, I learned this:

> Users are sometimes surprised by the value returned, for example why
> (-8)^(1/3) is NaN. For double inputs, R makes use of IEC 60559
> arithmetic on all platforms, together with the C system function
> ‘⁠pow⁠’ for the ^ operator. The relevant standards define the result
> in many corner cases. In particular, the result in the example above
> is mandated by the C99 standard. On many Unix-alike systems the
> command man pow gives details of the values in a large number of
> corner cases.

You can see more with the `?"^"` documentation.

The code can be resolved with:

```
as.complex(d)^1.2
```

Comment: I see, OK. I will come back to this later but I used the other approach.